# More input files in awk

Tags: awk

I have a code:

```
/Curve No./ { in_f_format=1; next } 
/^[[:space:]]*$/ { in_f_format=0; next } 
{sum2+=$2; sum3+=$3} END{printf("%.6f\n",sum3/sum2)}
```

That find a table in text file and provide a computation. The result is one number from one file.
How to get a column of results for more files. I wrote:

```
awk -f program.awk file??.txt
```

and I get only one result - for file01.txt

Input file01

```
    Curve     No. of obs.   Sum of squares
      1           82        0.81604656
      2         7200    96272.93714063
      3         7443   110384.79793831

jkjl
```

Input file02

```
    Curve     No. of obs.   Sum of squares
      1           82        0.81604656
      2         7200    96272.93714063
      3         7443   110384.79793831

jkjl
```

Desired input - two numbers in case of two input files.

```
14.034536
14.034536
```

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output.

Comment: I added it to my question

Comment: The result you get if for all the files combined. You'll want to add something like `FNR==1 { ... start over ... }` (the variable FNR holds the input line number within the current file.)

Comment: Do you want the results from EACH file, separately, or a single result from all files combined?

Comment: Single result from all files. I would like to get one file with one column of numbers - one number from one file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '
FNR==1{argind++}                          # if you are on GNU awk, remove this and...
/Curve No./ { in_f_format=1; next } 
/^[[:space:]]*$/ { in_f_format=0; next } 
{sum2[argind]+=$2; sum3[argind]+=$3}      # ... replace argind with ARGIND here
END{
    for(i=1;i<=argind;i++)                # ... and here.
        printf("%.6f\n",sum3[i]/sum2[i])
}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
14.034537
14.034537
```

If you are using GNU awk, you can replace `argind` with builtin `ARGIND` and remove the `FNR==1` block.

**Update**:

If you are on GNU awk you could use the[`ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html):

```
$ awk '/Curve No./ { in_f_format=1; next } 
/^[[:space:]]*$/ { in_f_format=0; next } 
{sum2+=$2; sum3+=$3} 
ENDFILE {                                   # ENDFILE after every file
    printf("%.6f\n",sum3/sum2)              # print 
    sum3=sum2=0                             # reset vars
}' file file                                # all those files
14.034537
14.034537
```

**Another update**:

Or you could move the `printf` and remove the `END` block:

```
$ awk '/Curve No./ { in_f_format=1; next } 
/^[[:space:]]*$/ { 
    in_f_format=0
    printf("%.6f\n",sum3/sum2)               # move it here
    sum2=sum3=0                              # reset vars
    next
} 
{sum2+=$2; sum3+=$3}' file file
14.034537
14.034537
```

Comment: It works for the example I gave here but I get wrong result by using it for original files

Comment: That is the technique anyway. If you output in the `END` block, you need to store the per file values to an array / arrays and index them somehow. If you are on GNU awk you could use [`ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html) instead.

Comment: @JamesBrown We're still watching you... just not so much ;-)

Comment: Why it doesn't work with http://leteckaposta.cz/827242331 ? I care about table on row 23656. Thank you

Comment: That link seems unrelated. Did you try the other version?

Comment: Thesecond version gives a mistake because of zero division, bude there si no zero in the second column as well as negative numbers, thus as can't be zero.

Comment: http://leteckaposta.cz/701744305 here is a link to input .txt in dos format. The previous was in unix, so that was probably the problem.

Comment: The division by zero comes from your original code `sum2+=$2 ... sum3/sum2` if there are no values in `$2`. Add `if(sum2)` before the `printf`. And I can't download neither of the files you linked.

Comment: And this link https://uloz.to/tam/_enOWYJVTZHls ? I followed your advice so there is no error about the division of zero, but I am confused about the result. It printed more numbers than I expected.

Comment: My czech is a bit rusty but I think I'd need to login. The page did not cooperate with Google translate either. Can't you just attach a bit of the non-working data to the question?